# How to preserve literal text from server side when displaying on client side?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

ASP.NET newbie question - fastest fingers!

I have a page that needs to pull some script off the server, including tag info, for the page.  Thus:

```
<html><body>
  blahblahblah
  <%: Model.TaggedField %>
</body></html>
```

Problem is, the value of `Model.TaggedField` may include HTML tags, but the page automatically converts the tag info to `&lt;myTag&gt;` etc.

What method can I call to make the value of `Model.TaggedField` be transmitted verbatim to the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <%= Model.TaggedField %> rather than <%: Model.TaggedField %>

Answer (score 1):

Remove the colon as this is shorthand for encoding.